# How to receive messages in real time with Telegram API in Android?

Tags: android, telegram

I want to use Telegram API to make an Android app, but it is not clear to me how to receive messages. I've seen a method called [getMessages](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getMessages) but this is not what I'm looking for. There is a posibility also to be notified by a [push notification](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates) but it is only valid if you are not connected to the server. So my question is, how can I connect to the server and receive messages in real time?

Comment: it's a long story:| but you may begin by looking at getdifference function at messagescontroller.java file.